# Google App Engine (Python SDK) - How to catch db exceptions

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using Google App Engine with Python and encountering errors like this:

```
raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property title is not multi-line
ERROR    2014-09-20 16:01:23,969 wsgi.py:278] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I've imported the db module: `from google.appengine.ext import db`

And I am attempting to silently (for now) catch the error with code like this:

```
try:
    r.put()
except db.Error:
    pass
```

Yet the error continues to break program execution. What am I doing wrong? (or not doing?)

Thanks...

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/myapp/myapp.py", line 191, in get
    date_last_modified = date_last_modified)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 970, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 614, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2847, in validate
    raise BadValueError('Property %s is not multi-line' % self.name)
BadValueError: Property column_series is not multi-line
```

Comment: Well for starters, you are catching the wrong exception. The exception is `BadValueError`.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: `db.BadValueError` is a  subclass of `db.Error`.

Comment: You have the right exception; but are you catching it in the right *location*? Please show us the full traceback.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - I've added the traceback.

Comment: @dmc7z: so while you are *setting* the property the exception is raised. Not when calling `r.put()`. See line 191 of your `get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is raised *while setting the attribute*; you can see the last part of the line where you should catch the exception in your code in the traceback:

```
  File "/Users/me/myapp/myapp.py", line 191, in get
    date_last_modified = date_last_modified)
```

You are creating or updating an instance there, and that's where the exception should be caught, not when calling `r.put()`.